# How can I create a UITableView for each property in a model?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary, struct

I have a struct that looks something like this:

```swift
internal class RemoteProfileModel: Decodable {
  let userId: String
  let company: String
  let email: String
  let firstName: String
  let lastName: String
  let department: String
  let jobTitle: String
  let pictureUri: URL?
  let headerUri: URL?
  let bio: String
  let updatedDate: Date
}
```

I need to list out these properties in a `UITableView`. I also need to use different cell types for some of the properties.

I'm thinking perhaps I should convert this struct to a dictionary of key/value pairs, and use the key to determine the cell type.

Is this possible? Is there another way to achieve this? I am unsure if it possible to convert a struct to a dictionary so am not sure this is the best way?

Answer (score 2):

to convert a class to a dictionary,

```
class RemoteProfileModel: Decodable {
    let userId: String
    let company: String
    let email: String

    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let department: String

    let jobTitle: String
    let pictureUri: URL?
    let headerUri: URL?

    let bio: String
    let updatedDate: Date


    init() {
        userId = "666"
        company = "AAPL"
        email = "hehe@163.com"

        firstName = "user"
        lastName = "test"
        department = "guess"

        jobTitle = "poor iOS"
        pictureUri = URL(string: "wrong")
        headerUri = URL(string: "none")

        bio = "China"
        updatedDate = Date()

    }

    func listPropertiesWithValues(reflect: Mirror? = nil) -> [String: Any]{
        let mirror = reflect ?? Mirror(reflecting: self)
        if mirror.superclassMirror != nil {
            self.listPropertiesWithValues(reflect: mirror.superclassMirror)
        }
        var yourDict = [String: Any]()
        for (index, attr) in mirror.children.enumerated() {
            if let property_name = attr.label {
                //You can represent the results however you want here!!!
                print("\(index): \(property_name) = \(attr.value)")
                yourDict[property_name] = attr.value
            }
        }
        return yourDict
    }
}
```

Call like this:

```
    let profile = RemoteProfileModel()
    profile.listPropertiesWithValues()
```

---

In Swift Debugging and Reflection,

A mirror describes the parts that make up a particular instance